# How to execute lines of text on the clipboard as bash commands

Tags: macos, bash, unix, clipboard

I'm working with Mac OS X's `pbpaste` command, which returns the clipboard's contents. I'd like to create a shell script that executes each line returned by `pbpaste` as a separate bash command. For example, let's say that the clipboard's contents consists of the following lines of text:

```
echo 1234 >~/a.txt
echo 5678 >~/b.txt
```

I would like a shell script that executes each of those lines, creating the two files a.txt and b.txt in my home folder. After a fair amount of searching and trial and error, I've gotten to the point where I'm able to assign individual lines of text to a variable in a `while` loop with the following construct:

```
pbpaste | egrep -o [^$]+ | while read l; do echo $l; done
```

which sends the following to standard out, as expected:

```
echo 1234 >~/a.txt
echo 5678 >~/b.txt
```

Instead of simply echoing each line of text, I then try to execute them with the following construct:

```
pbpaste | egrep -o [^$]+ | while read l; do $l; done
```

I thought that this would execute each line (thus creating two text files a.txt and b.txt in my home folder). Instead, the first term (`echo`) seems to be interpreted as the command, and the remaining terms (`nnnn >~/...`) seem to get lumped together as if they were a single parameter, resulting in the following being sent to standard out without any files being created:

```
1234 >~/a.txt
5678 >~/b.txt
```

I would be grateful for any help in understanding why my construct isn't working and what changes might get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> […] the remaining terms (`nnnn >~/...`) seem to get lumped together as if they were a single parameter, […]

Not exactly. The line actually gets split on whitespace (or whatever `$IFS` specifies), but the problem is that the redirection operator `>` cannot be taken from a shell variable. For example, this snippet:

```
gt='>'
echo $gt foo.txt
```

will print `> foo.txt`, rather than printing a newline to `foo.txt`.

And you'll have similar problems with various other shell metacharacters, such as quotation marks.

What you need is the `eval` builtin, which takes a string, parses it as a shell command, and runs it:

```
pbpaste | egrep -o [^$]+ | while IFS= read -r LINE; do eval "$LINE"; done
```

(The `IFS=` and `-r` and the double-quotes around `$LINE` are all to prevent any other processing besides the processing performed by `eval`, so that e.g. whitespace inside quotation marks will be preserved.)

Another possibility, depending on the details of what you need, is simply to pipe the commands into a new instance of Bash:

```
pbpaste | egrep -o [^$]+ | bash
```

---

**Edited to add:** For that matter, it occurs to me that you can pass everything to `eval` in a single batch; just as you can (per your comment) write `pbpaste | bash`, you can also write `eval "$(pbpaste)"`. That will support multiline `while`-loops and so on, while still running in the current shell (useful if you want it to be able to reference shell parameters, to set environment variables, etc., etc.).

Comment: +1 for an actual appropriate use of `eval`. Also, note that the pipe-to-bash option will allow multiline structures (e.g. the normal format for if and while statements), but the line-by-line option won't.

Comment: Wow, ruakh, thank you for that beautiful explanation and for the solutions! Following your and Gordon's lead, I kept playing with the pipe-to-bash option and found that I could eliminate `egrep` and `while` altogether. The following efficient construct handles even fairly complex multiline code (`while` loop, condition testing, variable incrementation, ...) perfectly: `pbpaste | bash`.